# Recursively rename all files and folders to Title Case from terminal

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I am a newbie and I have searched everywhere for this, I have also tried combining a lowercase renaming command with some regex to get Title Case instead of lowercase but I wasn't very successful.

This command converts everything (files + folders) inside the given folder to lowercase:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do mv -b -- "$file" "${file,,}"; done < <(find . -depth -name '*[A-Z]*' -print0)
```

And this is my attempt at title case, it works, but it is not recursive:

```
find . -name "*.flac" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do rename 's/(^|[\s\(\)\[\]_-])([a-z])/$1\u$2/g' *; done
```

Those are just some of my attempts, if there are better, shorter solutions I would pretty much like those instead.

Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, my files look like this: "09 - the Road to Home - Amy MacDonald.flac"; should be renamed to "09 - The Road To Home - Amy Macdonald.flac". Notice how there are already title cased words as well as uppercase letters in the middle of a word.

Comment: Only bash, oneliners? could be easily done with python.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Go for it, then ;-)

Comment: I am not very familiar with python. Sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the script below, you do not need more than the ability to paste :)

#### How to use

1. Paste the script below into an empty file, save it as (e.g.) `rename_title.py`
2. make it executable (for convenience reasons) `chmod u+x rename_title.py`
3. Run it with the directory to rename as argument:

   ```
   /path/to/rename_title.py <directory/to/rename>
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import shutil

directory = sys.argv[1]

skip = ["a", "an", "the", "and", "but", "or", "nor", "at", "by", "for", "from", "in", "into", "of", "off", "on", "onto", "out", "over", "to", "up", "with", "as"]
replace = [["(", "["], [")", "]"], ["{", "["], ["}", "]"]]
def exclude_words(name):
    for item in skip:
        name = name.replace(" "+item.title()+" ", " "+item.lower()+" ")
    # on request of OP, added a replace option for parethesis etc.
    for item in replace:
        name = name.replace(item[0], item[1])
    return name

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        split = f.find(".")
        if split not in (0, -1):
            name = ("").join((f[:split].lower().title(), f[split:].lower()))
        else:
            name = f.lower().title()
        name = exclude_words(name)
        shutil.move(root+"/"+f, root+"/"+name)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
        name = dr.lower().title()
        name = exclude_words(name)
        shutil.move(root+"/"+dr, root+"/"+name)
```

Examples:

```
a file > A File
a fiLE.tXT > A File.txt
A folder > A Folder
a folder > A Folder
```

And more complex, excluding `["a", "an", "the", "and", "but", "or", "nor", "at", "by", "for", "from", "in", "into", "of", "off", "on", "onto", "out", "over", "to", "up", "with", "as"]`:

```
down BY the rIVER for my uncLE To get water.TXT
```

becomes:

```
Down By the River for My Uncle to Get Water.txt
```

etc, it simply makes all files and folders (recursively) Title Case, extensions lower case.

EDIT: I have added all articles, conjunctions and prepositions that do not need to be capitalized according to the capitalization rules for song titles.

Comment: Works like a charm, could you also add a way to skip the title case command after converting everything to lowercase for some words like **to, the, in, as, for** (but not if at beginning of filename)?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I do not know yet but I think I can figure a way to add those myself to your code if needed. If you can do it for some words I can use your template to add more.

Comment: @BlackR should be pretty perfect now. Actually the result of an interesting question. It was *much* more complicated than I anticipated, but definitely challenging and very usable in a wider range of situations, since the rules you practice are simply proper naming rules. Thanks for the question!

Comment: Could you help me with adding some new functionality to your program? I would like to replace all parenthesis with brackets: ( becomes [ and ) becomes ], same for { and }. And I would also like to keep some words uppercase (TV, OP and ED; II, III, IV, V, VI ... IX - roman letters). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BlackR sure, I need to referesh my memory a bit though :) Shall I make an edit, referring to this comment? (probably not today).

Comment: Yes please, I would really appreciate it, if you could do it the same way (a list that's easy to edit). Thank you for your time!

Comment: @BlackR I refreshed my memory on trhe script. The parenthesis&co is a simple addition, The "Roman" letters however is quite complicated, since they are "normal" characters (capitals). Also, since the script, as it is, first lowers everything without looking, it needs a major rewrite (and will be more extensive) to exclude words/strings from that. Will look into it, but needs 1. more time, 2. A tight usable definition of roman stuff. Can I assume all combinations of I, V and X, in a row and surrounded by a space are roman figures?

Comment: You don't need to make it work for all roman figures, only 'I' to 'X'. 'I' is actually a single letter so it will get uppercased, same for 'V' and 'X'. You could just make another skip list that keeps certain words uppercase, and I'll add the roman figures there the same way I did for the prepositions&co. I should really learn python. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @BlackR Really, no trouble at all, but the cleanest way would be to add an extra function, to take care of both cases. An other exclude list works only in the other direction (*not* capitalizing defined strings)

Comment: @BlackR could you test this one: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/version.py if it works as meant, I'll post it (you still have to finish the list of "unchanged"). Don't hesitate to mention issues.

Comment: I have tested it and it apparently crashed mid-conversion. I don't know how to log events, but I tried to rename the following files: "07. barrowland (ballroom)" should become "07. Barrowland [Ballroom]", "11. The road To home (tv version)" should become "11. The Road to Home [TV Version]" and "08. L.a. vii" should become "08. L.A. VII". It got stuck on one of these, I'm pretty sure of it. I hope this helps.

Comment: @BlackR That is good information, will try if I get home tonight.

Comment: I looked into your example(s) but converting "08. L.a. vii" to "08. L.A. VII" in combination with all the other name converting options (two ways as I understand) including the surrounding possibly occurring split options (a dot as well as a space), all is very well possible, but I am afraid is really making things too complex for a quick solution as intended here. It would require a comprehensive recognizing system that is actually more a *piece of software* then a script as intended to be on AU I think. I am sorry.

Comment: It's okay. You have saved me a LOT of time already. I'll just have to go through my music library and rename what's left manually. Thanks again for your time and trouble!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `find`'s `-exedir`, then the names get passed any command with the leading components of the pathname removed, like `./sOmE fILE`. You could then title-case each sequence of word-characters that is preceded by either the leading `/` or by whitespace, e.g.

```
find path/ -execdir rename -nv -- 's/(?<=[\/\s])(\w)(\w*)/\u$1\L$2/g' {} +
```

Comment: Well, your command works only for the first letter. My filenames also contain blank spaces. Here is an example: 09 - the Road to Home - Amy MacDonald.flac; should be converted to 09 - The Road To Home - Amy Macdonald.flac. Please observe that there can be uppercase letters in the middle of a word as well as words already in title case.

Comment: Oops you are right of course - please see the revised version. I'm aware it doesn't exclude conjunctions (`in`, `to` etc.) as requested via your comments.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's useful info. You could use something like this perhaps: "rename 's/\b((?!(a|of|that|to)\b)[a-z]+)/\u$1/g' *". I think there is still the issue with skipping if at beginning of file name.