# How do I convert a highlighted string to 'Title Case' in Xbuntu, UbuntuStudio, or any Linux distribution using XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, ubuntu-studio

For example I might paste "the ingolfs of ignorina" into the subject line of an email (I did, see later if you are interested why) and want to quickly and easily change it to "The Ingolfs of Ignorina".

While searching for how to do this, I came across [Recursively rename all files and folders to Title Case from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589296/recursively-rename-all-files-and-folders-to-title-case-from-terminal) and was inspired to ask another question as follows:

**How do I selectively capitalise a highlighted string using various rules in Xbuntu, UbuntuStudio, or any Linux distribution using XFCE? The rules to apply could include among others:**

1. Title Case, usually used for song titles. I am reminded by [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm) that articles, conjunctions and prepositions do not need to be capitalised, for example

   > "Owner of a Lonely Heart"
2. Capitalise first letter of every word
3. Capitalise first letter of first word of every sentence
4. Capitalise first letter of proper nouns, for example

   > "victoria" becomes "Victoria"
5. Combine rules 3 and 4

**And finally, those pesky *ingolfs***

Why did I want to capitalise "The Ingolfs of Ignorina"?
I had a dream wherein I asked my father which opera featured a soprano aria where she sings passionately demanding to know something about "the Ingolfs of Ignorina". I even have the final bit of tune in my head, which I will post if I can figure out how to enter it into musical notation.

I woke up and searched for (you guessed it) "the ingolfs of ignorina" and drew a blank so I started an email to my father asking him and that's why I wanted to change a string to 'Title Case' which I searched for and drew another blank so that's why I have asked this question.

Please excuse me if I am getting off topic or even manic: it's the middle of the night, I just woke from a weird dream which wasn't even about ingolfs, and I'm sitting on the bed naked and shivering, writing questions about beings who might not even exist (I mean the ingolfs) and so far I have only written the subject line of the email to my father (without any capitalisation at all, as yet)!

Comment: There are tons of examples using the command line - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538676/uppercasing-first-letter-of-words-using-sed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705853/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-line-in-bash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370860/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-every-word-in-a-filename-or-directory-in-shell

Comment: @Panther Yes it's true that it can be done on the command line. However, I am asking for a way to do it with the mouse in a graphical user interface, such as a web-browser or other desktop application. Perhaps by right clicking and using the context menu.